# How to, at subclass, override exception defined at base class?

Tags: c#, exception, inheritance, overriding

In order to test inheritance and subclass overrides (the specific characteristics of a derived class, not necessarily with the 'override' keyword), I made these classes, meant to partially conjugate German language verbs.

The conjugation rules, oversimplified for my test, are as follows:

- the infinitive of the verb must end either in **-en** or **-rn**. Otherwise, an exception for invalid data must be thrown, both for the base class and the subclass.
- regular verbs (base class) have their 3rd person singular (he-person) ending in **-t**. In case this regular verb form does not end in **-t**, an exception must be thrown for the base class.
- a set of irregular verbs (called "modal" verbs) has its 3rd pers. sing. NOT in **-t**. In case the **-t** ending is detected, an exception must be thrown for the subclass.

The problem is: two of the aforementioned exceptions contradict each other. The irregular-verb class is meant to inherit most of the content from the regular-verb class, but it inherits the "no -t ending" exception, which it is supposed to override, so that its specific exception is thrown for the opposite reason.

My code is as follows:

The main class (GermanVerb), whose properties are the infinitive and the first three grammatical persons (I, you, he):

```
namespace HeyCs.MyClasses;

internal class GermanVerb
{
    internal GermanVerb(string infin, string thirdPer)
    {
        if (infin.EndsWith("en") || infin.EndsWith("rn"))
            Infin = infin;
        else
            throw new InvalidDataException("The infinitive doesn't obey the expected    grammatical rules.");

        /*
        if (!thirdPer.EndsWith("t"))
            throw new InvalidDataException("The 3rd person singular doesn't obey the expected grammatical rules.");
        */

        if (!thirdPer.EndsWith("t"))
            thirdPer += "t";

        ThirdPer = thirdPer;
        FirstPer = Infin.Substring(0, Infin.Length - 1);

        if (ThirdPer.EndsWith("st"))
            SecPer = ThirdPer;
        else if (ThirdPer.EndsWith("t") && !ThirdPer.EndsWith("st"))
            SecPer = ThirdPer.Substring(0, ThirdPer.Length - 1) + "st";
        }

        private string? Infin { get; }
        internal string? FirstPer { get; set; }
        internal string? SecPer { get; set; }
        internal string? ThirdPer { get; set; }


        public void VerbConjSum()
            Console.WriteLine(Infin + ": " + FirstPer + ", " + SecPer + ", " + ThirdPer);
}
```

Note that I commented out the exception I wanted to throw, because it's inadvertently inherited by the subclass GermanVerbLikeModal, even if I try to define a new condition for the InvalidDataException to occur. Instead, I set a temporary workaround, in which the -t ending is automatically added to the he-form of the regular verb, in case it's absent.

Here's the code for the subclass:

```
namespace HeyCs.MyClasses;

internal class GermanVerbLikeModal : GermanVerb
{
    internal GermanVerbLikeModal(string infin, string thirdPer) : base(infin, thirdPer)
    {
        if (thirdPer.EndsWith("t"))
            throw new InvalidDataException("The 3rd. person singular doesn't obey the expected grammatical rules.");

        ThirdPer = thirdPer;
        FirstPer = ThirdPer;

        if (ThirdPer.EndsWith("ss"))
            SecPer = ThirdPer + "t";
        else
            SecPer = ThirdPer + "st";
    }
}
```

And here's the Program.cs file, where I create an instance of a regular verb, and an instance of an irregular verb:

```
using HeyCs.MyClasses;

var trinkenVerb = new GermanVerb("trinken", "trinkt"); // Verb 'trinken', meaning 'to drink'
var sollenVerb = new GermanVerbLikeModal("sollen", "soll"); // Verb 'sollen', meaning 'should'


trinkenVerb.VerbConjSum();
sollenVerb.VerbConjSum();
```

The result in the console is:

```
trinken: trinke, trinkst, trinkt
sollen: soll, sollst, soll
```

I mentioned it just to give context to my problem. This is the expected output with valid data: for both verbs, infinitive in -en. For the 3rd person, -t ending for base verbs, non-t-ending for derived verbs.

So, I want to create three custom exceptions. One of them is common to both classes. Meanwhile, these classes have a unique exception each. But the subclass keeps inheriting the contradicting exception that it is meant not to inherit: activating the 'absent -t' exception for the base class, the verb "sollen" throws an exception because of the 'soll' form.

Even though I found a workaround, which omits the 'absent -t' exception altogether, is there a way to cancel that exception specifically for the subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method overriding

add this method to the Base class and call it from the constructor:

```
protected virtual void CheckThirdPer(string thirdPer)
{
    if (!thirdPer.EndsWith("t"))
        throw new InvalidDataException("The 3rd person singular doesn't obey the expected grammatical rules.");
}
```

Override the method in child class

```cs
protected override void CheckThirdPer(string thirdPer)
{
     if (thirdPer.EndsWith("t"))
          throw new InvalidDataException("The 3rd. person singular of a modal verb doesn't end in '-t'.");
}
```

Comment: Wow! Simpler than I thought. So I just have to encapsulate the conditional function into another function. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle this would be to offload checks into separate functions, each responsible for one check. This way, you can `override` specific behavior for each check.
As an example, your main class may look like this:

```cs
namespace HeyCs.MyClasses;

internal class GermanVerb
{
    internal GermanVerb(string infin, string thirdPer)
    {
        if (!infin.EndsWith("en") && !infin.EndsWith("rn"))
            throw new InvalidDataException("The infinitive doesn't obey the expected grammatical rules.");

        Infin = infin;

        if (!thirdPer.EndsWith("t"))
            HandleThirdPer();

        if (!thirdPer.EndsWith("t"))
            thirdPer += "t";

        ThirdPer = thirdPer;
        FirstPer = Infin.Substring(0, Infin.Length - 1);

        if (ThirdPer.EndsWith("st"))
            SecPer = ThirdPer;
        else if (ThirdPer.EndsWith("t") && !ThirdPer.EndsWith("st"))
            SecPer = ThirdPer.Substring(0, ThirdPer.Length - 1) + "st";
    }

    private string? Infin { get; }
    internal string? FirstPer { get; set; }
    internal string? SecPer { get; set; }
    internal string? ThirdPer { get; set; }


    public void VerbConjSum() => Console.WriteLine(Infin + ": " + FirstPer + ", " + SecPer + ", " + ThirdPer);
    protected virtual void HandleThirdPer() => throw new InvalidDataException("The 3rd person singular doesn't obey the expected grammatical rules.");
}
```

And your subclass like this:

```cs
internal class GermanVerbLikeModal : GermanVerb
{
    internal GermanVerbLikeModal(string infin, string thirdPer) : base(infin, thirdPer)
    {
        ThirdPer = thirdPer;
        FirstPer = ThirdPer;

        SecPer = ThirdPer.EndsWith("ss") ? ThirdPer + "t" : ThirdPer + "st";
    }
    protected override void HandleThirdPer() { }
}
```

Comment: So, in the subclass, the overridden HandleThirdPer() just does nothing at all?